# How do I plot with x-axis scaled down by a fixed quantity?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, axis-labels

Say I have the following code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lis = random.sample(range(1, 5000), 4000)

plt.plot(lis)
```

This plots the following:

[image]

The x-axis is printed from 0 to 4000 with a step size of 1. But I want it to be 0 to 4 with a step size of 0.0001.

I tried this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lis = random.sample(range(1, 5000), 4000)

plt.plot(lis)
plt.xlabel(np.linspace(0, 4, num=40001))
```

But this does not do the job:

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.plot()` can take only one array as an argument (i.e. `plt.plot(y)`), then it interprets it as y values and plots it simply over the indices, as in your example. But if you want different x values, you can simply put them before the y values in the argument list like `plt.plot(x, y)`, with x being your x value array, which obviuosly should have the same length as y.

In your case this would mean

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lis = np.random.randint(0, 5000, 4000)
x = np.arange(0, 4, 0.001)
plt.plot(x, lis)
```

See the docs for further reading: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Comment: This gives the following error: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (4000,) and (4001,)`

Comment: Instead, if we define x as follows, `x = np.linspace(0, 4, num=4001)`, then it works fine.

Comment: Then you silently redefined `lis` because `lis = random.sample(range(1, 5000), 4000)` leads to 4000 values: `np.shape(lis) -> Out: (4000,)`

Comment: Haha, no actually my `lis` is defined in a function like so: `lis=[]
i=0
while i<=4:
    lis.append(x(i))
    i+=0.001`

So that's why it was happening.